# I have 4 stacked images that I want to zoom in on & scale one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have four images stacked on top of each other. On hover, the visible image zooms-in and fades-out to reveal the image beneath.

I have two problems that I'm trying to solve:

1st. as the image scales, it bleeds outside of the containing div. I want the image to scale but, keep the image area outside of the div hidden.

2nd. Once the first image is fully faded, I want the now visible image to do the same as the first and reveal the image beneath. Currently it just sits there with the mouse pointer hovering over it.

So, I have a relatively positioned  container that holds 4 absolutely positioned images. One of which, I have wrapped in another div to try to keep the overflow of the image hidden (this dosn't work).

I have used CSS to transform both the opacity and scale over a duration of 2s, which works for the first image, but not the subsequent image beneath it.

What I am trying to do is to reproduce a presentation that I put together (on Adobe Spark) as a website. I have spent a couple of weeks researching the kinds of effects that I am after, but only seem to come up with various JavaScript/jQuery plugins.

Is what I am trying to do above not simple enough to use just CSS transforms and transitions? My idea was to get these sorted and then look at invoking the styles when a user scrolls up/down the website using JavaScript preferably, or jQuery if that proved too complicated.

```css
/* create a relatively positioned wrapper 
        fpr the images */

.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 25vw;
  z-index: 10;
}


/* fit absolute container to top left of img-wrapper.
        Fill the width of the wrapper */

.stack {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}


/* stack the image centered in the img-wrapper */

.img-1 {
  z-index: 4;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.img-1:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%) scale(1.25);
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.img-2 {
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.img-2:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%) scale(1.25);
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.img-3 {
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.img-3:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.img-4 {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.img-4:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF8" lang="eng">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
<header>Header Text</header>
<main>
  <h1>4 Images placed Over Each Other</h1>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <!-- 'overflow: hidden' to stop image bleed outside of div
            which doesn't work :( -->
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
      <img class="stack img-1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502359521992-f86fd62e12dd" alt="african chillites">
    </div>

    <img class="stack img-2" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509085051020-b0707cdec216" alt="african chillites">
    <img class="stack img-3" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526179969422-e92255a5f223" alt="indian chillies" alt="african chillites">

    <img class="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518843875459-f738682238a6" alt="fresh veg" alt="african chillites">

  </div>
</main>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

As I have tried to describe, I expected the transform/transition to cascade down the stack as each image beneath is fully revealed. This is clearly not the case and only works for the very top image.

As for the image bleeding outside of the div as it scales, I'm not sure what else to try other than `overflow: hidden;` on the container, which doesn't work. If i apply that style to the `class="img-wrapper` div, the images just dissappear!

Any help or suggestions as to where to go with this would be much appreciated.

Update:

I added working links to images so that there is a usable demo of the problem I am trying to solve.

Many thanks to all that can contribute.

Addendum

I thought I would add this working example to clarify what I am trying to achieve:  [Adobe Spark example](https://spark.adobe.com/page/b0PHE9uBNNOdx/). This works on real mobiles that I have tried (various Samsung touch screens) and also Chrome & Firefox 70.0.1 dev tools responsive view but, it does not work in Firefox Developer edition 71.0b9 (64-bit) responsive view.

My main hurdle is the stacked images that zoom/fade-in-out as the user scrolls. I tried Skrollr with great success on desktop, but there's no way to make it work on mobile.

If there are any suggestions for alternative plugins/libraries that could achieve my goals, I would be greatfully thankful to hear of them. I think attempting to my own JavaScript to do this is one step too far for my programming abilities ot the moment! :-/

Thanks for reading.

Comment: A transform does not affect the *actual* size of an element. From the looks of it (**without a working demo**) I'd suggest that since the transformed element is still on top and effectively 100% size, it's blocking any hover affecting anything under it.

Comment: The images don't disapear. The reason why they don't show up is because the wrapper doesn't known the image size & height from it's grand-child.

Comment: @Paulie_D, Yeh! I pretty much suspected that was why the images beneath weren't responding to the transforms. Do you know of a solution to the problem?

Comment: @JensIngels Hmm. I cant really specify a specific size in absolute dimensions, px for instance, because I want them to be responsive to the size of the screen/viewport, do you have any suggestions on this front given the code above?

Comment: Have you considered using viewport units? (vw, vh). If css doesn't work out. You can just JavaScript to calculate it like "let w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
let h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);". Keep in mind of scrolling bars tho. It might help to calculate a min as well.

Comment: @JensIngels, I think the JavaScript method is going to be the way to go. Thank you for your feedback. Skrollr does what I need on desktop, but not mobile. This is something like what I am trying to achieve: [Adobe Spark example](https://spark.adobe.com/page/b0PHE9uBNNOdx/) This seems to work on moblie, not Firefox browser dev tools responsive mode, but Chrome dev tools yes, real mobile yes! My main hurdle is the zoom/fade-in-out of stacked images. Thanks agin.